# TypeError: string indices must be integers while Using Gerrit rest API for extracting data in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, gerrit

I'm getting the error mentioned above when I'm trying to fetch the data over gerrit rest API. 
The code is as follows:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 
from pygerrit2.rest import GerritRestAPI 
import os 
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass') headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'} 
rest = GerritRestAPI(url='testgerriturl.com', auth = auth) 
changes = rest.get("changes/?q=all&o=DETAILED_ACCOUNTS&n=5", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) 
data={'status':[]}

for change in changes:
       for d in change:
            data['status'].append(d[u'status'])
```

The json I'm using is of type:

> {     u 'status': u 'MERGED', u 'topic': u 'master_e', u 'updated': u
>   '2018-09-04 05:40:19.000000000', u 'insertions': 549, u 'created': u
>   '2017-08-31 08:03:05.000000000', u 'change_id': u
>   'I7ed2f8da71e38f4908acf92f36dd', u 'hashtags': [], u 'deletions': 178,
>   u 'submitted': u '2018-09-04 05:39:48.000000000', u 'submittable':
>   False, u 'project': u 'testdemo', u 'branch': u 'master', u 'owner': {
>         u 'username': u 'usertest',         u 'email': u 'user@abc.com',        u
>   'name': u 'userdemo',         u '_account_id': 36710  }, u '_number':
>   71090131, u 'id': u 'fm~master~I7ed71f4908acf92f36ddac3ff85b271e', u
>   'subject': u '%TBC FC: OSS_FC_0 App_NBI: RESTful Web Service Data
>   Access API- PM Support : add IUM scripts' }

I want output in the form as:

```
{'status': ['MERGED'], 'deletions': [178], 'updated': ['2018-09-03 20:58:26.000000000'], 'insertions': [664], 'created': [2018-08-28 08:16:56.000000000']}
```

I'm doing something wrong here, can somebody please correct me what needs to be done here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

```
changes = { u'status': u'MERGED', u'topic': u'master_e', u'updated': u'2018-09-04 05:40:19.000000000', u'insertions': 549, u'created': u'2017-08-31 08:03:05.000000000', u'change_id': u'I7ed2f8da71e38f4908acf92f36dd', u'hashtags': [], u'deletions': 178, u'submitted': u'2018-09-04 05:39:48.000000000', u'submittable': False, u'project': u'testdemo', u'branch': u'master', u'owner': { u'username': u'usertest', u'email': u'user@abc.com', u'name': u'userdemo', u'_account_id': 36710 }, u'_number': 71090131, u'id': u'fm~master~I7ed71f4908acf92f36ddac3ff85b271e', u'subject': u'%TBC FC: OSS_FC_0 App_NBI: RESTful Web Service Data Access API- PM Support : add IUM scripts' }
data={'status':[], 'deletions':[], 'updated':[], 'insertions':[], 'created':[], }

for k, v in data.items():
    if k in changes:
        data[k].append(changes[k])
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'status': [u'MERGED'], 'deletions': [178], 'updated': [u'2018-09-04 05:40:19.000000000'], 'insertions': [549], 'created': [u'2017-08-31 08:03:05.000000000']}
```